# What is the magazine the Dark Lord reads?

Tags: the-devil-is-a-part-timer

In *Hataraku Maou-sama!*, there is a magazine that appears in the Dark Lord's apartment on more than one occasion. It seems to read something like "yoride-FF".

[image]
[image]

Is this any existing magazine, or a reference to some existing magazine, with a distorted name (like MgRonald)? If so, what is its genre/target audience/content?
Or is it a completely non-existing magazine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the textual factors, the magazine shown is very likely a reference to [月刊サンデージェネックス](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%88%E5%88%8A%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%82%A7%E3%83%8D%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9) ([Monthly Sunday Gene-X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monthly_Sunday_Gene-X)), which is also known as 月刊サンデーGX.

Let us have a closer look at the magazine in the picture:

[image: Cropped]

- "月刊" printed at the top, and "Monthly Yonday" printed vertically at the side of the spine of the magazine tell us that it is a monthly magazine.
- The text at the bottom of the spine reads "Kougakukan", which is most likely a reference to [Shougakukan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shogakukan) ([小学館](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F%E5%AD%A6%E9%A4%A8)), which is the publisher of the actual magazine 月刊サンデーGX.
- The logo of the magazine (月刊ヨンデーFF) has close resemblance to the logo of [月刊サンデーGX](http://sundaygx.com/). There is also the fact that there is only a difference of 1 Katakana, and how 2 English alphabet is used at the end of the name.

  [image: Logo]

  <sup>Logo is taken from http://sundaygx.com/</sup>

However, the logo as seen from the spine of 月刊サンデーGX magazine doesn't perfectly match up with the image from Hataraku Maou-sama. The screenshot below show how the spine of the magazine in 2006/2007 looks like (can't find a more recent image). The word 月刊 is separated from サ in the actual magazine, compared to the fictional magazine in Hataraku Maou-sama, where 月刊 is placed on top of ヨ. There might be a second reference here that I do not know of.

[image: Screenshot]

<sup>Image taken from http://blog-imgs-27-origin.fc2.com/n/a/0/na005/20070204-1.jpg</sup>